# PageRequestManagerParserErrorException when changing Response during AJAX request

Tags: asp.net, telerik, updatepanel, httpresponse, internet-explorer-10

I get an exception after clicking on a button or performing somekind of ajax operation inside AjaxPanel.

> SCRIPT5022: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled.
>   Details: Error parsing near '
>
> < !DOCTYPE html>. 
>   Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd, line 15 character 16238

On ASP.NET 4.0 with `Telerik`. This happens only on IE10. Meaning - works perfectly on chrome, Mozilla, previous IE.

I applied the hotfixes KB2600088 and KB2783767 on the server but still nothing. This is Windows Server 2003 Standard Edition 32-bit.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

> clicking on a button or
>
> What can I do?

If you are modifying the **HttpResponse** state, it is necessary to **move** this "button"
**from** the Telerik AjaxPanel/MS UpdatePanel.

See the [Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException - what it is and how to avoid it](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2007/02/26/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception-what-it-is-and-how-to-avoid-it.aspx) blog post for more information.

Comment: Hi, you should notice that this works perfectly on other browsers except IE10.. hence I assume it's a problem relating to some IE10 change in rendering or something...

Comment: Try switching to the IE9 Browser/Document mode and keep the Script Debugging enabled. What are your results?

Answer (score 2):

This problem is related to ajax request cycle and the problem solution is in webresources cache object is being treated by browser as unhandled request.

to resolve the problem the call trace must be captured using any web resource monitor and it is always advised to have request with timestamp or unique identifier.

unmannaged ajax requests under browser shows this type of error sometimes this also shows 500 error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I faced to this error few months ago when I migrate from IE 9 to IE 10.

It seems there is(are) an(some) incompatibility issue(s) between ASP.NET AJAX Client Library 4.x and IE 10.

I found changing compatibility settings of IE, would resolve my problem. I added following line:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

at top of my page as first line of html head section, before every other tags (as follow),

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
    ...
```

PageRequestManagerParserErrorException never occurred again, but some IE10 specific CSS3 rules did not affect because of changed compatibility setting.

I recently wrote this situation to [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/805516) and they told they are investigating.